# gnuplot line for every distinct value in one column

Tags: ubuntu, plot, gnuplot

I have the following data where TCM* / TEM* are different instances. the first column is the time in seconds. I measure the cpu usage, the ram usage and the amount of RAM in MB in column 3-5. For now I want to plot the CPU usage for every instance in a graph.

The graph should have the first column (seconds) as x-axis and the third as y-axis. The second value should be treated like that: For every distinct value there should be one line in the graph. So the graph would have 9 lines.

How can I do that?

```
 0 TCM1     10.5    2.9     29900
 0 TCM2     5.3     3.0     30380
 0 TEM1     10.5    2.9     29816
 0 TEM2     15.8    2.9     29792
 0 TEM3     5.3     2.9     29752
 0 TEM4     5.3     2.7     27908
 0 TEM5     15.8    2.7     27752
 0 TEM6     26.3    2.9     29716
 0 TEM7     10.5    2.7     27728
 1 TCM1     5.2     2.9     29900
 1 TCM2     10.5    3.0     30380
 1 TEM1     5.2     2.9     29816
 1 TEM2     10.5    2.9     29792
 1 TEM3     10.5    2.9     29752
 1 TEM4     10.5    2.7     27908
 1 TEM5     5.2     2.7     27752
 1 TEM6     10.5    2.9     29716
 1 TEM7     5.2     2.7     27728
 2 TCM1     24.8    2.9     29900
 2 TCM2     5.0     3.0     30380
 2 TEM1     5.0     2.9     29816
 2 TEM2     5.0     2.9     29792
 2 TEM3     5.0     2.9     29752
 2 TEM4     9.9     2.7     27908
 2 TEM5     9.9     2.7     27752
 2 TEM6     9.9     2.9     29716
 2 TEM7     5.0     2.7     27728
 3 TCM1     16.7    2.9     29900
 3 TCM2     11.1    3.0     30380
 3 TEM1     11.1    2.9     29816
 3 TEM2     22.2    2.9     29792
 3 TEM3     16.7    2.9     29752
 3 TEM4     5.6     2.7     27908
 3 TEM5     22.2    2.7     27752
 3 TEM6     16.7    2.9     29716
 3 TEM7     5.6     2.7     27728
 4 TCM1     8.6     2.9     29900
 4 TCM2     8.6     3.0     30380
 4 TEM1     8.6     2.9     29816
 4 TEM2     4.3     2.9     29792
 4 TEM3     13.0    2.9     29752
 4 TEM4     8.6     2.7     27908
 4 TEM5     4.3     2.7     27752
 4 TEM6     4.3     2.9     29716
 4 TEM7     8.6     2.7     27728
 5 TCM1     20.6    2.9     29900
 5 TCM2     10.3    3.0     30380
 5 TEM1     5.2     2.9     29816
 5 TEM2     5.2     2.9     29792
 5 TEM3     5.2     2.9     29752
 5 TEM4     5.2     2.7     27908
 5 TEM5     5.2     2.7     27752
 5 TEM6     5.2     2.9     29716
 5 TEM7     5.2     2.7     27728
 6 TCM1     11.0    2.9     29900
 6 TCM2     16.4    3.0     30380
 6 TEM1     11.0    2.9     29816
 6 TEM2     21.9    2.9     29792
 6 TEM3     27.4    2.9     29752
 6 TEM4     5.5     2.7     27908
 6 TEM5     21.9    2.7     27752
 6 TEM6     21.9    2.9     29716
 6 TEM7     11.0    2.7     27728
 7 TCM1     9.6     2.9     29900
 7 TCM2     9.6     3.0     30380
 7 TEM1     4.8     2.9     29816
 7 TEM2     4.8     2.9     29792
 7 TEM3     9.6     2.9     29752
 7 TEM4     14.4    2.7     27908
 7 TEM5     4.8     2.7     27752
 7 TEM6     9.6     2.9     29716
 7 TEM7     9.6     2.7     27728
 8 TCM1     22.3    2.9     29900
 8 TCM2     11.2    3.0     30380
 8 TEM1     11.2    2.9     29816
 8 TEM2     11.2    2.9     29792
 8 TEM3     5.6     2.9     29752
 8 TEM4     5.6     2.7     27908
 8 TEM5     11.2    2.7     27752
 8 TEM6     5.6     2.9     29716
 8 TEM7     11.2    2.7     27728
 9 TCM1     11.1    2.9     29900
 9 TCM2     11.1    3.0     30380
 9 TEM1     5.6     2.9     29816
 9 TEM2     22.3    2.9     29792
 9 TEM3     22.3    2.9     29752
 9 TEM4     5.6     2.7     27908
 9 TEM5     5.6     2.7     27752
 9 TEM6     5.6     2.9     29716
 9 TEM7     11.1    2.7     27728
```

Comment: You could chop the file up with `awk` into 9 different files, then use gnuplot with `plot 'file1' w l, 'file2' w l`, etc

Comment: ok, that works. is that the simplest way?

Comment: If you don't want to dig deeper into gnuplot, then I think so. You could use `plot for [j=1:9] 'file'.j. w l` to get a one-liner if you call the files `file1` etc.

Comment: or make one file with 9 new-line separated chunks of data and plot it, that will also give you 9 separate lines.